# Convert timeformat to a acceptable format for strftime

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have a service that accepts in the body request a field called `datetime_format` that would a string that suggest the datetime format in the `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss` format.

I have to use this format to then pass through pandas for analyzing a dataset.

Issue is pandas and generally python, use a different timeformat for `strftime` (or more in general) that is the `%y/%m/%d` etc..

What I'm trying to achieve is that user would still send me the format in the yyyy/MM/dd and all the different possibilities of it, but internally convert to a format that would be acceptable for python.

Something like:

- yyyy -> %y
- MM -> %m

etc..

I could probably try to write a custom function with a dictionary, but I was wondering if there was already something out there.

Comment: Just write that dictionary...

Comment: Boring! but yup I don't think I have other options, right

Comment: Well, less boring and more dangerous way is to try to guess the date without knowing format at all, see: https://percentagent.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or search for any other date guesser...